# Access Controls collection at MVC template level Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I need to remove an object from the PageHandler Header Controls collection in my page template.

I can use the below script to do so at the widget view level, however the one I need to remove has not yet been added at that point, so I need to move it right before it's consumed.

The only accessible place for it that I could find is in my template file - right before `@Html.Section("head")`. I'm trying to remove the default canonical URL for this template only (some crazy routing stuff going on in this site... don't ask).

```
    var pageHandler = this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Handler.GetPageHandler();
    foreach (var c in pageHandler.Header.Controls)
    {
        if (c != null && c is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink mylink = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink)c;
            if (mylink.Attributes["rel"] == "canonical")
            {
                pageHandler.Header.Controls.Remove(mylink);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to use this in the template file inside the `<head>` tag `pageHandler.Header` is null.

1 - Am I accessing this object in the wrong way for this particular template level? If so, what's the proper object reference?

2 - Is it simply not set yet because of some behind-the-scenes page construction order in Sitefinity? If so, where could/should I handle accessing this object?

3 - Something else is going on entirely?

---

**I AM NOT ASKING HOW TO FIX A NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION**

*I understand that the object is null and am trying to find where in the Sitefinity viewmodel at this level this data might be found.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical url is set in Page_PreRenderComplete event which fires after your code in the view has executed.

What I would do is create a new widget, e.g. CanonicalUrlRemover.

In its Index method find the Page object and subscribe to its PreRenderComplete event. Then in the event handler remove the canonical url.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var page = HttpContext.CurrentHandler.GetPageHandler();

   page.PreRenderComplete += Page_PreRenderComplete;            

   return new EmptyResult();
}

private void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var page = sender as System.Web.UI.Page;
   if (page != null)
   {
       var headerControls = page.Header.Controls;
       foreach (var c in headerControls)
       {
           if (c != null && c is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink)
           {
              System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink mylink = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink)c;
            if (mylink.Attributes["rel"] == "canonical")
            {
                headerControls.Remove(mylink);
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Just drop the widget in this particular page template and you are good to go.

Comment: Can I just get your phone number? Lol

Comment: you gotta do this in answer_successful event handler :)

Comment: So it fires in the page admin, but not on the front end (user facing page). Because it's a blog post, could this have something to do with the action?

Comment: Yeah that was exactly it, added:
        `protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
        {
            Index().ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
        }`